# jQuery: infinite loop through array... each()?

Tags: jquery

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/F6nJu/

I have a colored box:

```
<div id="colorblock"></div>
#colorblock { background:#3ff; width: 100%; height: 300px; }
```

I have an array of colors created in javascript:

```
var arr = [ "#f00", "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66"];
```

I iterate through those colors with a jQuery `each()` function:

```
$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
  $('#colorblock').delay('1200').animate({backgroundColor:value}, 600);
});
```

When the array iterates to the end, how can I start the array iteration over (so the animation goes on forever)?

Comment: Why iterate when you can just use array indexes? `i=0; arr[i++ % arr.length]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var arr = ["#f00", "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66"];

// run through the array forever
(function recurse(counter) {
    // get the colour
    var color = arr[counter];
    // animate it
    $('#colorblock').delay('1200').animate({
        backgroundColor: color
    }, 600);
    // delete the value to save memory
    delete arr[counter];
    // add the value at the end of the array
    arr.push(color);
    // run it again for the next number
    setTimeout(function() {
        recurse(counter + 1);
    }, 200);
// start it for the first number.
})(0);
```

Infinite recursion. Delete the current entry, then add the current value to the end.

[`Live Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/JJfKM/20/)

For those who are interested in what the array looks like:

```
["#foo", "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66"] (counter = 0)
[undefined, "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66", "#foo"] (counter = 1)
[undefined, undefined, "#f0f", "#f66", "#foo", "#ff0"] (counter = 2)
[undefined, undefined, undefined, "#f66", "#foo", "#ff0", "#f0f"] (counter = 3)
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "#foo", "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66"] (counter = 4)
etc.
```

Comment: i assume you are using my `set_color` function?

Comment: please... (we are here to learn so... ;) The last line of your code: `})(0);` i played with numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3. Interesting things happend. What is this exactly?

Comment: @roXon added more details / comments.

Comment: @Raynos... You are so kind! You just earned a +10! (I just can't find the button ;) well... +1

Comment: Perfect solution... but how to toggle it? I'm trying using jQuery .toggle() with stop() on recurse()...

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var arr = ["#f00", "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66"];
$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
    set_color(value);
});

function set_color(color) {
    $('#colorblock').delay('1200').animate({
        backgroundColor: color
    }, 600);
    setTimeout(function() {
        set_color(color);
    }, 2000); //restart in 2 seconds
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/F6nJu/1/

Comment: this works, thank you! the setTimeout() function does not seem to work, but no matter, as I have set a delay before the animation.

Comment: @Neal... why is there a setTimeout if delay is set? ... if I remove the timeout the animation stops. What is actually doing setTimeout? thanks in advance!

Comment: @superUntitled, its 2 secs for that color, not any color

Comment: @roXon `setTimeout` is recursing the function

Comment: $.each for an array that isn't jQuery elements? Yuck. Use a for or while loop.

Comment: @Matt! wowowowowo stop here! This is getting interesting! may you change a bit the fiddle please? How shoud it look like with **for** - or with **while** loop? (Thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.prototype.recurse = function(callback, delay) {
   delay = delay || 200; 
   var self = this, idx = 0;

   setInterval(function() {
      callback(self[idx], idx);
      idx = (idx+1 < self.length) ? idx+1 : 0;
   }, delay);
}
```

Try it on StackOverFlow:

```
["#f00", "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66"].recurse(function(item, index) { 
    $('body').css('background-color', item);
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["#f00", "#ff0", "#f0f", "#f66"];

(function recurse(counter) {
    var arrLength = arr.length;
    var index = counter%arrLength;

    var color = arr[index];

    $('#colorblock').delay('1200').animate({
       backgroundColor: color
     }, 600);

    setTimeout(function() {
       recurse(counter + 1);
    }, 200);

})(0);
```

Comment: Being posted 5 years after question was asked and accepted I recommend you add some details on why this solution is better