# jquery --Chnage the background color in cyclic order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div with background color red . on clicking this div background color should change in cyclic order .. red, green and gray.. the cycle should continue.

i don't want to use any jquery plugins to achive this

please refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkHz3/)

Comment: ok, start writing the code, and we will help you

Comment: Even though you did not want to use jQuery plugins, I thought this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051567/325742) by @Raynos  was a great way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKqBy/)

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>​

div {
  background: #3f3;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;    
}

var cur = 0;
var colors = ['#3f3', '#f33', '#33f', '#ff3'];

$('.myDiv').click(function() {
    cur = (cur + 1) % colors.length;
    $(this).css('background', colors[cur]);
});   ​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data` to store current state:

```
var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']

$('#box').click(function () {
    var box = $(this);
    var index = box.data('current-index') || 0;
    index++;
    if (index >= classes.length)
        index = 0;
    box.data('current-index', index);

    box.removeClass(classes.join(' '));
    box.addClass(classes[index]);
});
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/jD6XK/