# Restart jQuery.each() after loop ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I have array of values and i want to set those values as placeholders to my input.

How to achieve this using `jQuery.each()` **only** because i solved my issue with  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051471/jquery-infinite-loop-through-array-each) and it works perfectly.

I tried doing this to restart it but it's not working:

```
if(index==arr.length) index=0;
```

**HTML code:**

```
 Values : <input name='input' id='input' />
```

**JS/jQuery code:**

```
var arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    arr.push('Value ' + i);//fill array with values
}

function eachChange(){
   var x=0;
   $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
       x++;
   setTimeout(function(){ 
       $('input').attr('placeholder', value);
      }, x * 1000); 
       if(index==arr.length) index=0;

 });   

}
eachChange();//call function
```

**Fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/5ZQgX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with trying to restart a `.each()` loop this way. First and foremost, that's not how `.each()` really works. It's less a loop and more shorthand for calling the function on every element. If you gave that anonymous function a name (let's go with `setPlaceholder()`), the `.each()` call is essentially doing this:

```
setPlaceholder(0, arr[0]);
setPlaceholder(1, arr[1]);
setPlaceholder(2, arr[2]);
setPlaceholder(3, arr[3]);
setPlaceholder(4, arr[4]);
setPlaceholder(5, arr[5]);
```

The index value it passes to the function isn't used for looping purposes, so trying to set it to 0 won't have any impact on the `.each()` call.

The second issue is your if condition. It'll never actually fire, since the final "iteration" of the `.each()` call will have `arr.length - 1` as its value, not `arr.length`.

I'm not sure why you want to have it keep looping, but if that's your goal, you could accomplish it like this:

```
function eachChange(){
    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('input').attr('placeholder', value);
        }, index * 1000);
        if (index == arr.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(eachChange, (index + 1) * 1000);
        }
    });   

}
eachChange();//call function
```

What that should do is schedule `eachChange()` to be called again 1 second after the last placeholder update takes place. You can add in some other checks to limit the number of times it recurses, but if you want it to happen indefinitely that should do the trick.

[Here's an updated fiddle demonstrating it.](http://jsfiddle.net/95mX7/)

Answer (score 1):

you can compare the index with the arr.length like this

```
var arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    arr.push('Value ' + i);//fill array with values
}

function eachChange(){
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('input').attr('placeholder', value);
   //if it is the last element in arr setTimeout and call eachChange() 
   if(index>=arr.length-1){
        setTimeout(function(){  
           eachChange();     
        },1000);
   }

  }, index * 1000); 
});   

}
eachChange();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R274P/1/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can reset the counter of the $.each function, as it seems to encapsulate a simple for loop. You dont have access to the counter from the outside.

However, try:

```
function eachChange(initX){
   var x = initX || 0;
   $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
       x++;
       setTimeout(function(){ 
          $('input').attr('placeholder', value);
       }, x * 1000); 

       // Call yourself but pass current x
       if(index==arr.length) eachChange(x); 

   });   
}
```

Remove the initX part if you want x to reset, but i assume you want it to keep counting from where the previous loop finished.